# How do I import Typescript types from an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I'm using an NPM package Constate (https://github.com/diegohaz/constate). In `node_modules/constate`, it includes several type definition files:

```
constate/
  dist/
    ts/
      src/
        types.d.ts
  src/
    types.ts
```

And in Constate's `package.json`, it has:

```
"types": "dist/ts/src",
```

I'm trying to import a type from either `types.ts` or `types.d.ts`. I tried:

```
import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate/dist/ts/src/types';
import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate/dist/ts/src/types.d';
import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate/dist/ts/src/types.d.ts';
import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate/src/types';
import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate';
```

None of these work. What's the proper convention to import types from an NPM module? What's the purpose of the `types` field in `package.json`?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Does `import constate from "constate"` work? They use this in almost all of their examples.

Comment: Seems like types are not exported from the package.

Comment: `import { SplitValueFunction } from 'constate/dist/ts/src/types';` works for me, my TS version is 3.9.7. You can restart TS server and try again.